# Django migrations, change parameters for column, without losing data

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-migrations

I need to change parameter for the column

```
 name = models.CharField(db_column='UserName', max_length=30,
                                     blank=True, null=True)
```

need to change on this

```
 name = models.CharField(db_column='UserName', max_length=100,
                                     blank=True, null=True)
```

how I can change parameter `max_length` without losing data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing only `max_length` will not affect anything except for changing the field's character length and you are **not going to loose any data** also.

You just need to makemigrations and migrate again.

> python manage.py makemigrations

You will get something like this on the terminal after entering above command

```
Migrations for 'employee':
  employee/migrations/0002_auto_20170409_0246.py:
    - Alter field name on employee
```

and then migrate

> python manage.py migrate

Comment: feel privileged to help you @Maic